# Make guitar pedal power supply go from 120mA to 300mA

Tags: power-supply, capacitor, guitar-pedal

I have a power supply that takes 220V DC and provides five galvanic isolated 9V DC, 120mA sockets to power electric guitar pedals.

Now I have a guitar pedal that consumes 300mA. I want to mod the power supply to have one of the sockets providing up to 300mA.

**What components have to be replaced to go from 120mA to 300mA here?**

Here is a photo with labels of the components:

[image: photo of the open power supply]

The voltage regulators on the bottom have an output voltage of 9V.

Comment: Are you sure this produces 9V AC? The bridge rectifiers and 7809s don't make any sense if it does, those are for DC supplies.

Comment: of course you are right, I edited my question

Comment: Is that supply an Alctron DCT-5 which is a 5x9VDC 5x120mA isolated supply?

Comment: Please post a link to a guitar pedal that consumes and heats with 9V x 300mA= 2.7W.

Comment: @Audioguru https://www.thomann.de/intl/flamma_fs02_reverb.htm

Comment: @Justme No, it’s this (although the label absolutely points in that direction): https://www.thomann.de/intl/harley_benton_powerplant_junior.htm

Comment: @baumschubser It could be an identical rebranded product.

Comment: Looks like you are right, the case is very similar. Although the Alctron is marked as 5x50mA

Comment: I read it wrong, it is marked as 5x120mA, just as the Harley Benton.

Comment: I do not know why they say it consumes the very high 300mA of current.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Essentially nothing.  The core of the transformer does not mind how you draw the power out.  The windings may do.  The voltage regulators are good for 1A *with* *sufficient* *cooling*.  That's your likely point of trouble, and you may want to pick the most free-standing regulator and see whether you can put a heat sink on it.  Don't let heat sink or regulator touch the case, or alternatively, omit the heat sink but mount the regulator directly to the case electrically isolated using an appropriate mica piece and plastic grommet for isolation (every electronics shop has them for various cases, this one being a TO-220), and thermal paste.

If you want to, you can increase the size of the corresponding 1000µF capacitor in order to have less ripple but I doubt it is necessary.

Keep the total draw limited to 600mA, though, in order not to overtax the transformer.

Comment: Thank you, will try if it works with an isolated heat sink on it. The other answers gave me a good understanding of the overall problem, but this is the thing I will try and if it does not work I guess I'll just buy another power supply.

Comment: @baumschubser "The windings may do" means the windings may mind.  You can measure the resistance in place (I doubt the Ohmmeter will use a probe voltage passing the bridge rectifier's 1.2V threshold) and then calculate (.3A)²·R to get an estimate of the power loss in the windings.  But it's quite inaccurate since .3A is the average current and the power loss depends on RMS current which gets lower with higher duty cycle (one reason _not_ to increase the capacitor since an increase lowers the duty cycle).

Answer (score 1):

There may be no components you can change. And to be fair, nobody knows why the output is rated for 120mA each, we don't know if the limitation is from transformer coil rating for current, or just how much the parts heat up.

If the transformer outputs are rated for 120mA only, it may heat up more than designed and degrade faster, as it can't provide 300mA.

Same for the regulator, it has to dissipate more power and may heat up too much.

If you don't count for the transformer itself, or the regulators just heating up too much, the circuit can otherwise give out 9V at 300mA just fine, so there is nothing you can mod there.

The bridge rectifier should be good enough, the 1000uF bulk capacitor should be large enough to handle 12V AC rectified peaks of 16-17V dropping to 12V at 400mA load, the regulator handles enough current but will heat more at average of 1.5W which is a lot.

There just is a limit what you can do with the transformer itself and what you can do with the linear regulators and the heat dissipation ability of the chassis. You can't even connect the regulator tab to metal chassis for heat diasipation without electrical insulation, as it would not be isolated any more.

What you could do instead is to use this supply as a reference and build your own with known transformer which is rated for required current and linear regulators bolted to heatsinks for handling the heat.

Or just buy a separate 9V 300mA supply for your special device.

Comment: The current rating could come from the transformer design.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible you don't need to change any components *per se*, as the L7809 is good for 1.5 Amps output. But, it's likely you would need to increase the heatsinking. The one at the top of your picture, by itself, right next to a sheet of alli, would be the best channel to choose for the 'higher output' channel. Bolt it with an insulating heatsink washer to the alli panel if extra heatsinking is needed.

That 7809 is a nice component to do experiments like this with, as it's overcurrent and overtemperature protected. Just draw 300 mA from it and see what happens. If it overheats, it will shut itself off, cycling between off and on as it heats and cools, so you will know it needs more heatsinking to keep it happy.

Assuming those 1000 uF capacitors are the post-rectifier reservoir capacitors, then 120 mA output would cause 1 V droop, and 300 mA would cause 2.4 V droop. You may get away with that, or you might want to increase the value, maybe to 2.2 mF or 4.7 mF, or just wire another 1000 uF in parallel.

The bridge rectifiers are fine. The transformer windings are likely to be OK, as long as you keep the total output load within the 600 mA. The extra heat in the 300 mA channel will be offset by less heat in the other channels.

Answer (score 0):

1. As in another answer, it looks like one of the regulators is positioned well for heatsinking.  BUT - the mounting tab of a 7809 is *not* insulated; it is connected to pin 2, the device's GND pin.  If connected to the frame, that output will not be completely floating.  The output GND for that circuit will be tied to earth ground by the green/yellow wire.  Whether or not this is a problem depends on the circuits and internal wiring of the downstream devices.

If you need this output to be fully isolated, the solution is an insulated mounting kit.  This usually is an insulated shoulder washer, a mica or silicone pad that is thermally conducting but electrically insulating, and maybe nylon hardware.

2. The supply is clearly marked as having 12 V outputs, not 9 V.
3. 5 x 12 V x 100 mA = 6 W, and with regulator headroom, the max total load would be (guessing) around 9-12 W.  The transformer core looks large enough to handle that.  The 100 mA current limit could be due to nothing more than having no direct contact heatsinks for the regulators.  A TO-220 package can handle 2 W internal dissipation (not output power), but it is very hot at that power level.  For good long-term reliability, its continuous power dissipation must be much lower.  As in #1, a physical heatsink solved this.

Another possible power limitation is the wire gauge used in the transformer.  If so, increasing the power demand on one winding will cause it to heat up more than the others.  But if the other windings are not running at full rated current, the transformer core should be able to move the excess heat of one winding.  Note that at 2.5x the rated current, the output voltage for that winding will be less than the other windings.  This could have consequences for the regulator.  See #4.

4. If the output current of a regulator circuit is going to be more than doubled, the bulk filter capacitor for that circuit has to at least double.  This will prevent the negative peaks of the ripple voltage from being so low that the regulator pulls out of regulation.  If this happens, you will be able to see it on the DC output as a trace that is flat most of the time, but has periodic negative-going dips at twice the power line frequency.

Also, as in #3, the rectified voltage going into the regulator will be less than for the other outputs.  The positive peak voltage will be less, so the bulk filter cap will be "topped off" at a lower voltage, so there will be less headroom (the difference in voltage value between the peak input voltage and the minimum peak input voltage needed for a clean output).  A larger bulk filter cap compensates for this by storing more energy between peaks so it discharges more slowly, and still has enough voltage across it to support regulation all the way until the next peak comes along.

Comment: The whole supply isn't marked for 12V. The AC transformer is clearly marked for 12V. It is said to have 7809 regulators so there is no reason to believe the supply is marked and has 12V outputs.